# how to load the navbar and the page content correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron

I have my `nav.html` file that contains the navbar. How can I decide when the rest of the data goes?

because when I load my navbar as follow:

```
<body>

    <div id="navbar">

    </div>

    <div id="page-wrapper">

    </div>
</body>

<script>
$(function(){
    $("#navbar").load("./navbar/index.html");
});
</script>
```

the content of the `navbar` is covering the content of `page-wrapper`

how can I load the navbar and the content of the page together without messing up the page content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you are just having a styling issue. Just make some tweaks to your CSS or inline page styling and you will fix this issue.